# How to make a generic class implement interface

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have this generic class:

```
public static class ListBuilder<T> where T : class
{
   public static void Build(XmlElement element, string elementeName, ref List<T> lista)
   {
         XmlNodeList nl = element.GetElementsByTagName(elementeName);

         if (nl != null && nl.Count > 0)
         {
            for (int i = 0; i < nl.Count; i++)
            {
                element = (XmlElement)nl.Item(i);

                T item = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), element);

                if (!lista.Contains(item))
                   lista.Add(item);
            }
         }
    }
}
```

And I call this method from a lot of parts of my project:

```
Util.ListBuilder<Alerta>.Build(element, "alerta", ref retorno);
```

I need to turns all my pages, less coupled, so, I am now converting all my code to be able to receive unit tests.

My first step is to remove coupled declarations, substituting something like that:

```
private Alerta _alerta;
```

Into:

```
private IAlerta _alerta;
```

So, I will need to transform the call above, into something like that:

```
Util.ListBuilder<IAlerta>.Build(element, "alerta", ref retorno);
```

But, when I try to convert my Util method to accept it, like that:

```
public static class ListBuilder<T> where T : IBaseInterface
{
   public static void Build(XmlElement element, string elementeName, ref List<T> lista)
   {
         XmlNodeList nl = element.GetElementsByTagName(elementeName);

         if (nl != null && nl.Count > 0)
         {
            for (int i = 0; i < nl.Count; i++)
            {
                element = (XmlElement)nl.Item(i);

                T item = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), element);

                if (!lista.Contains(item))
                   lista.Add(item);
            }
         }
    }
}

public interface IBaseInterface
{
}

public interface IAlerta : IBaseInterface
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Titulo { get; set; }
    string Mensagem { get; set; }
    DateTime DataAlerta { get; set; }
}

public class Alerta : IAlerta
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Titulo { get; set; }
    public string Mensagem { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataAlerta { get; set; }
}
```

The IBaseInterface, is implemented in all my interfaces.

But I am getting an error, saying that I need to have a parameter less constructor. But an interface do not has a constructor.

I dont know if this is the right way to do that, but I need to isolate all my pages classes, removing all classes references/dependencies from the code, changing to interfaces, to permit to implement unit tests, with less dependencies.

What I need to do ?

Thanks.

Comment: Generic constraints can help you to ensure a parameterless constructor must be present in T - `new()`.

Comment: You should specify the type of a class, not an interface, when you declare the closed generic type, so `Util.ListBuilder<Alerta>.Build(element, "alerta", ref retorno);`

Comment: public static class ListBuilder<T> where T : IBaseInterface,new()

Comment: Side note: you only need `ref` on a parameter if you're going to *reassign* the variable or mutate a `struct`. Neither appears to be the case here.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your question is incorrect. The code you provided won't give that error as you don't have a `new()` constraint on the class and you call `Activator.CreateInstance` with one parameter.

But indeed you can't instantiate an interface anyway. You will need to rethink your design. This method in your ListBuilder class is the culprit:

```
T item = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), element);
```

You ask the runtime to instantiate an instance of `T`, which in your case is `IAlerta`, so an interface type:

```
Util.ListBuilder<IAlerta>.Build(element, "alerta", ref retorno);
```

This means that the generic code above translates in this case to

```
IAlerta item = (IAlerta)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(IAlerta), element);
```

This will indeed always fail, since you can't instantiate an interface.

What you can do:

- call the `Build` method with the concrete type as before (why are you introducing the interface exactly? It seems unnecessary since your `Alerta` class is a simple object)
- pass a function `Func<XElement,T>` to instruct the method on how to construct an instance of `T`, something like this:

  ```
  public static class ListBuilder<T> where T : IBaseInterface
  {
     public static void Build(XmlElement element, 
                              string elementeName, 
                              ref List<T> lista, 
                              Func<XElement,T> ctor)
     {
           XmlNodeList nl = element.GetElementsByTagName(elementeName);

           if (nl != null && nl.Count > 0)
           {
              for (int i = 0; i < nl.Count; i++)
              {
                  element = (XmlElement)nl.Item(i);

                  T item = ctor(element);

                  if (!lista.Contains(item))
                     lista.Add(item);
              }
           }
      }
  }
  ```